# Web browser Back button should keep on same JSP instead of previous jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have multiple JSP pages ,and i am redirecting user from one JSP to another JSP.Suppose i am having JSP1,JSP2 and JSP3 and i am redirected user from JSP1 to JSP2.
**Problem:** If user is currently on JSP2 and if he/she press back button of browser it's redirecting user from JSP2 to JSP1.

**Requirements:** what i want is if user press back button of browser it should not redirect to JSP1 it should keep user on JSP2.

Comment: Are you doing a redirect or a forward in the JSP?

Comment: If the user clicks the back button, it means they want to go back - not stay on the same page. Does JSP2 have its own history of states which you can go back in?

Comment: actually jsp1 is calling servlets and that servlets is redirecting to jsp2 by calling  response.sendRedirect("URLOfJsp2");I am storing some session attribute and request attributes  <form name='verifyUser' action="verifyUserServlets" method='POST'>

Comment: @Juan I am using redirect

Comment: Have you tried using forward instead? Forward happens on the server side.

Comment: I will try to use forward()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RequestDispatcher.forward**

This method (**forward()**) is used to pass the request to another resource for further processing within the same server, another resource could be any servlet, jsp page any kind of file.This process is taken care by web container when we call forward method request is sent to another resource without the client being informed, which resource will handle the request it has been mention on requestDispatcher object which we can get by two ways either using ServletContext or Request. This is also called server side redirect.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("pathToResource");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Or

```
RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**SendRedirect ():**
This method is declared in HttpServletResponse
This method is used to redirect client request to some other location for further processing ,the new location is available on different server or different context.our web container handle this and transfer the request using  browser ,and this request is visible in browser as a new request. Some time this is also called as client side redirect.

Comment: Good Explenation, i make chages to use forward method